# How to match use Fuzz with array input

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I want to try to get match values from the two arrays I input. I use Fuzzy for that. but I still can't get that value, maybe because the input form is an array. help me, please :)

Thank you and I'm sorry if my question does not clear. Thank you :)

```
a = [
      [
        "nyeri",
        "tekan"
      ],
      [
        "nyeri",
        "pada",
        "kulit"
      ],
      [
        "demam"
      ]
   ]

b = [
      [
        "nyeri",
        "tekan"
      ],
      [
        "pembengkakan",
        "pada",
        "kulit"
      ],
      [
        "demam",
        "tinggi"
      ]
   ]
```

I tried the following code :

```
c = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(b):   
    
        Matching = fuzz.ratio(a,b)
        
        if len(a) == len(b) and Matching == 100:
            c.append([a, 'value:', 1])  
        elif len(a) != len(b) and 90 <= Matching <= 99:
            c.append([a, 'value:', 0.8])
        elif len(a) != len(b) and 80 <= Matching <= 89:
            c.append([a, 'value:', 0.7])
        elif len(a) != len(b) and 70 <= Matching <= 79:
            c.append([a, 'value:', 0.6])
        elif len(a) != len(b) and 0 <= Matching <= 69:
            c.append([a, 'value:', 0])
        return jsonify(c)
```

expected result :

```
[
      [
        "nyeri",
        "tekan"
      ], 
      "value:", 1
      [
        "nyeri",
        "pada",
        "kulit"
      ],
      "value:", 0
      [
        "demam"
      ],
      "value:", 0
]
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Is there any example where `value` should take a value not equal to 1 or 0?

Comment: @TedBrownlow, like this, value  = 72 or 0.6,


`a = [
      [
        "thank",
        "you",
  "very",
  "much",
  "for",
  "your",
  "answer",
   ]
 ]     

b = [      
      [
        "thank",
        "you",
  "very",
  "much",
      ]
   ]`

Answer (score 2):

You're taking the fuzz ratio on the overall `a` object. `i` and `j` are completely unused. I assume that this is closer to what you're actually attempting.

```
c = jsonify([
  fuzz.ratio(a_element,b_element)
  for a_element in a
  for b_element in b
])
```